# Android Studio: trouble with getResourceAsStream() in TSAGeoMag.java

Tags: android, classpath, android-resources, filenotfoundexception

UI'm developing an Android app using Android Studio on a Windows 10 computer. I have a MainActivity.java and a TSAGeoMag.java. The latter is a third-party program downloaded from ngdc.noaa.gov that computes magnetic declination (the difference between magnetic and true north). It uses some sort of coefficients located in a WMM.COF file. These lines are creating problems.

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("WMM.COF"); 
if(input == null) throw new FileNotFoundException("WMM.COF not found");
```

FileNotFoundException is thrown no matter what path I put in quotes.
I've put the WMM.COF in the same folder as the java files **and **in the "res" folder. I've tried all kinds of different quoted strings for different paths in the above code. I've tried "../res/WMM.COF", "../../res/WMM.COF, /WMM.COF. I've read that getResourceAsStream() uses the classpath. I don't know what that is in my situation, so I tried this (I figured hard coding an absolute path would help) with and without the leading backslash:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/Jim/AndroidStudioProjects/SunriseSunset2/app/
src/main/res/WMM.COF"));
```

input is null with this also. Do I need special user permissions in my androidmanifest.xml?
The image is my directory structure as shown in Android Studio

[image: 1]

I've tried what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to use that file directly as `InputStream`, then you should put it into the `raw` folder inside the `resource` folder.

**res -> raw -> wmm.COF**

Note that you have to convert the file name to lowercase otherwise, it won't get compiled.

Now, just use the code you were already using.

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("WMM.COF"); 
if(input == null) throw new FileNotFoundException("WMM.COF not found");
```